# Every surjective function has a right inverse

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am studying the counterpart of the axiom of choice in ETCS which is that "Every surjective fucntion has a right inverse". I am trying to see why it implies the axiom of choice and this is the paragraph i am studying at the moment.

Let  $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be the surjective function and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ be the right inverse. Noticing that a surjective function represents a non empty set  of a disjoint non empty set and that disjoint sets are  $f^{-1}(y)$ for each $y$ in $Y$. Then $g: Y \rightarrow X$ is a choice for every $y$ in $Y$ as $g$ picks out one element of $f^{-1}(y)$. Therefore, the existence of $g$ is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

I can't make sense of the "$g: Y \rightarrow X$ is a choice for every $y$ in $Y$ as $g$ picks out one element of $f^{-1}(y)$".

I studied the definition of the axiom of choice as "given a non empty set $A$,  it is possible to choose an element from each subset $a$ in set $A$"

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Can you check your notation again? You now have used $g$ for both the function $X \to Y$ and $Y \to X$. And you have said nowhere what $f$ is (these might be related). Also, it would be good if you say what exactly you take as the definition of the axiom of choice. Because there are many equivalent definitions.

Comment: I have now corrected the type. Thank you for pointing it out